# How can I pass the results of Python's help('modules') output to pbcopy in one line?

Tags: python, macos, unix, terminal, copy-paste

Just like the title addresses, how can this be done? I stupidly tried the following, but I will share the stupidity here so you can get an idea as to what I want to happen:

`myself$ python help('modules') | pbcopy`

---

Is this a good idea:

```
fout = open('output.txt', 'w')
fout.write(help('modules'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my Ubuntu, and hopefully on your boxen too (as it is a standard python feature), there is the handy [`pydoc`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pydoc.html) command, thus it is very easy to type

```
pydoc modules | pbcopy
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is pbcopy, but I gouess this woul do the trick:

```
 python -c 'import urllib; help(urllib)' | pbcopy
```

at least this is definitely works:

```
 python -c 'import urllib; help(urllib)' > file
```

From `man python`:

```
 -c command
          Specify the command to execute (see next section).  This terminates the option list (following options are passed as arguments to the command).
```

### Update:

In order to copy this to clipboard you can add this to `~/.bashrc`:

```
pc() { python -c "import $1; help($1);" | xclip -i -selection clipboard; }
```

then just call `pc logging` or `pc my_module`

Or you can pipe it to pbcopy or what ever works for you.

Comment: `pbcopy` allows you to pipe the output to the console to your clipboard.

Answer (score 0):

Use [pydoc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pydoc.html) to look up documentation and print it.

Example:

```
$ python -c 'import pydoc; print pydoc.getdoc(id)'

id(object) -> integer

Return the identity of an object.  This is guaranteed to be unique among
simultaneously existing objects.  (Hint: it's the object's memory address.)
```